# Writing columns of data into a text file

Tags: matlab

I'm using the following code to write the vectors `sortedthresh_strain` and `probofdetectionanddelamprop1` into a text file. However, the text file output is as follows:

0.0030672   1.6592e-080.0033489 5.1721e-080.0034143

where 0.0033489 5.1721e-08 should be on the next line of the text file. i.e. It should be:

0.0030672   1.6592e-08
0.0033489   5.1721e-08

I am unsure of how to do this.

**Edit**: Using the proposed answer:
0.0049331   0.0049685   0.0049894   0.0050094   0.005156    0.0051741   0.0052139   0.0053399   0.0054486   0.0056022   **7.0711e-21**  **3.0123e-19**

The 2nd column is required to contain:
7.0711e-21
3.0123e-19

And,

```
dlmwrite('THRESHUNCERTAINTYFINALPLOTLSIGMA5.dat'[sortedthresh_strain,probofdetectionanddelamprop1],'delimiter', '\t');
```

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768864/write-cell-array-into-text-file-as-two-column-data/22768954#22768954

Comment: @AndyCampbell Thanks, but I am using R2013a.

Comment: Do you have the statistics toolbox? If so, then you may want to look at the dataset obejct in that toolbox which is similar and can be exported to a file: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.export.html

Comment: @AndyCampbell Sorry. I am unsure how to use `dataset` for my situation. I don't understand the Name/Value pair portion. Could you please help in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have R2013b or later, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768864/write-cell-array-into-text-file-as-two-column-data/22768954#22768954). If you have an earlier version but have the statistics toolbox you can use the dataset object to do this very easily just like tables in R2013b. Using dataset:

```
data1 = {'a','b','c'}'
data2 = [1, 2, 3]'
ds = dataset(data1, data2)
export(ds, 'file', 'data.txt')
```

If you don't want the variable names in the result text file you can use `'WriteVarNames', false` in your call to export.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is in row vectors, but should be column vectors for it to work like you want.

Just add a transpose with '.

```
dlmwrite('THRESHUNCERTAINTYFINALPLOTLSIGMA5.dat',[sortedthresh_strain',probofdetectionanddelamprop1'],'delimiter', '\t');
```

Comment: Thanks. No, my data is in fact column vectors and thus the transpose doesn't sort the problem out. I've edited the question to include this output.