# write cell array into text file as two column data

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have two different variables which are stored as cell arrays. I try to open text file and store these variables as two column arrays. Below is my code, i used \t to seperate x and y data, but in the output file, the x data is written first which is followed by the y data. How can I obtain two column array in the text file?

```
for j=1:size(data1,2)
    file1=['dir\' file(j,1).name];
    f1{j}=fopen(file1,'a+')
    fprintf(f1{j},'%7.3f\t%20.10f\n',x{1,j}',y{1,j});
    fclose(f1{j});
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dlmwrite` as well to accomplish this for numeric data:

```
x = [1;2;3]; y = [4;5;6]; % two column vectors
dlmwrite('foo.dat',{x,y},'Delimiter','\t')
```

This produces the output:

```
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a MATLAB table if you have R2013b or beyond:

```
data1 = {'a','b','c'}'
data2 = {1, 2, 3}'
t = table(data1, data2)
writetable(t, 'data.csv')
```

More info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html).